# How to search for lines from one file in another in linux

Tags: linux

I have file1 and file2. I need to search and print out if any line in file1 exists in file2. If not exists, I need to know there is no entry exists by any way. How can I achieve this in linux command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need grep:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

If you want process file1 as fixed string, not regex pattern, parameter -F need be added.

```
grep -F -f file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

grep can do this task.

`grep -f File1 File2`

However other commands like `diff` and `cmp` can also be used.